# need a drop down that have text at there right end under dropdown boundry

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is link what i exactly want to create.

https://screenshots.firefox.com/KyQN5mJcuHqcdDxS/null

Comment: Image url not working

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a very broad question

Comment: I have uploaded but it is not working and don't know why. let me check once again

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten i have tried but i am unable to add text on it.

Comment: @user4035772 *What* have you tried? Please update your question to include **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and your relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten
<select class="form-control" id="test" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                   
                                </select>
                                <span class="select-group-addon">mm</span>
Css : .select-group-addon {
    margin-left: -90px;
    color: #666;
}
#test{
    padding-right: 85px;
}

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46686387/edit) with the required information. You have also shown no attempt whatsoever at trying to do this yourself, which makes your question off topic and subject to get closed. Please do some basic research, and give us enough information to help us be able to help you.

Comment: @FluffyKitten have you not check my code that what i have did.
If you do not want to help me then leave it for others who can help me.

Comment: Update **your question** with the required information. An image is no good to us.

Comment: @awsme-sandy image url is working Now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by one of my friend:

Plese see the below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/meshsoni/185a9chb/3/

```css
/* Custom dropdown */
.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width:150px;
}

.custom-dropdown select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.custom-dropdown::before,
.custom-dropdown::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-dropdown::after { /*  Custom dropdown arrow */  
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    right: 60px;
    top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
    z-index: 3;
}

.custom-dropdown::before { /*  Custom dropdown arrow cover */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 9999;
    content: 'mm';
    background: #afa9a9;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.custom-dropdown::after {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="custom-dropdown big">
       <select class="form-control" id="width" required>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="hi">hi</option>
          <option value="hello">hello</option>
       </select>
</div>
```